# Firebase best practice: dealing with periods (e.g. an auction) ending?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've not been able to find a comprehensive answer on this and would be grateful for some feedback from those in the know.

**The context:**
Let's say you are building an auction app, like eBay, using Firebase database. Users can set up their own auctions, and can choose the duration (which gets stored in firebase as, for example, an 'endsAt' timestamp). At the end of the period, the app needs to do some processing, and alert the relative people. Moreover, you want this to occur in a timely fashion, because people may be observing the auction as it ends.

***So: what is considered best practice for closely monitoring and responding to timestamps in firebase?***

**Potential solution**
The way I'm going with at the moment is:

1. A firebase function which looks at all the 'live' auctions every minute, triggered by a cron job on a server (e.g. app engine), and deals with those that have ended since it was last run.
2. If a user is actually observing the auction as it ends on their devices (i.e. you don't want a potentially 60-second wait at 0 seconds), the processing functions will be triggered from that user's own device.

Is there a better way that I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: I use the same process as you do. I created a cloud functions that update a RealTimeNode from a call made periodically from chron-job.org

Comment: "what is considered best practice for closely monitoring and responding to timestamps in firebase" Interesting fact about a timestamp is that it doesn't change. So you can read it once, and then just monitor progress towards it client-side. Any data modification rules that use the timestamp can be applied in Firebase's server-side security rules, but the client can do most of its work by simply reading the value (or monitor it for infrequent changes) and then applying logic in the app.

Comment: Christophe's comment is also totally valid btw: using a cron-job to update time-based state transition. But before Cloud Functions existed, I used to do those from various clients and that worked fine too (as long as you ensure those updates are idempotent - i.e. can run multiple times with the same outcome).

Comment: Thanks both - it seems therefore that a mix of client-side observation (which can provide immediate responses) and periodic server-side checks (totally reliable, but not immediate) is indeed the best way to go about it. This is really helpful to know.